# Import JavaScript file into JavaScript and use functions

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of JavaScript functions, which I would like to have in separate JS files and be able to import them and use the functions in the main JS file like so

TestFunction.js:

```
function test(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
```

Main.js:

```
CODETOIMPORTHERE TestFunction.js
test('test!');
```

Comment: Are you executing this in a browser ? Do you need a fancy module solution or would the usual simple solution be OK ?

Comment: The JavaScript would be executed in the browser yet. But I would like to be able to just import the code within the main.js file, as that would look a lot more clean if possible.

Comment: If it's in a html document you can use `document.createElement('script')` and set the `src` attribute to the path where TestFunction.js is located.

Comment: So if I was to do something like: http://pastebin.com/FKrABDyc

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Looked almost everywhere. Exactly what I needed. How can I mark this as a dupe?

Comment: you can simple put reference of both files in your main `html` file

Comment: @JakeCross Be careful that most answers (including the accepted one) in the linked QA are terribly obsolete. Look at the answers referring to standard module solutions (AMD, requirejs, etc.)